# Visual Studio Team Services doesn't get the packages folder for VS 2015 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

**Background:**

- I have an MVC application recently ported to Visual Studio 2015 Pro
- All relevant references are set to `Copy Local` = `True`
- We are using Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online)  for our repository
- I am able to compile, publish, and run the application locally without issues
- All dlls contained in the `\packages` folder are not getting committed to Team Services and NuGet isn't fixing this on the other machines.

How do I fix this so everyone else can compile this application?

I have read many "solutions" to this problem, but none have worked. One that seems to fix the issue for many people doesn't work in `VS2015` because Microsoft removed the option to automatically restore NuGet packages.

I have searched many other sites, and similar posts on Stack, but none are exactly this issue.

Please help me fix it.

Comment: You should not commit the contents of the `packages` folder to source control. Packages will be restored automatically during build. The behavior you're talking about was removed because it's **deprecated** in favor of a different method of package restore that doesn't require any modifications to the project files or use of custom MSBuild targets. What specific problem are you having with package restore?

Comment: What's the error when other people restore the nuget packages? And can the build been built successfully from VSO? If not, can you share the error logs?

Comment: After hours of digging, I fix it. I deleted the `\packages` folder, then built the application. It all works.